# Change Background color of a particular cell of an updatable browse widget in progress 4gl

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I want to change the background color of a particular cell of an updatable bowse widget in progress 4gl(openedge abl)

I tried fetching the column using GET-BROWSE-COLUMN and then used BGCOLOR to change the background color of the cell. But it only changes the first cell of that column . I want to change multiple cells of the same column(not all cells) after updating the cells when a particulr condition occurs.

Answer (score 4):

The ROW-DISPLAY Trigger is used for conditional coloring of browse cells.

You need to grab the column's handle outside the ROW-DISPLAY trigger, like in the Main Block of the procedure.

Defitions:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE hCell AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
```

Main-Block:

```
hCell = BROWSE {&browse-name}:GET-BROWSE-COLUMN (1) .
```

ROW-DISPLAY Trigger:

```
ON ROW-DISPLAY OF BROWSE-2 IN FRAME DEFAULT-FRAME /* Browse 1 */
DO:
    IF Customer.Salesrep = "HXM" THEN 
        hCell:BGCOLOR = 3 . 
    ELSE 
        hCell:BGCOLOR = ? .
END.
```

More samples:

- https://community.progress.com/s/article/P71083
- https://community.progress.com/s/article/21627
- https://community.progress.com/s/article/20602

Comment: the above code changes the background color of only first row of column. i want to change background color of multiple rows.